# The data redaction policy replace expression works different than regexp_replace function

Tags: oracle

Oracle 12c

`select c_name from table1;`

c_name

---

YYY NNN

ZZZZZ

`select regexp_replace(c_name, '(YYY)(.*)', 'XXX\2') from table1;`

c_name

---

XXX NNN

ZZZZZ

it's correct behaviour

But DBMS_REDACT.ADD_POLICY gives incorrect result:

```
DBMS_REDACT.ADD_POLICY(object_schema=>'SCOTT'
, object_name=>'TABLE1'
, policy_name=>'test_redact_policy'
, column_name=>'C_NAME'
, function_type=>DBMS_REDACT.REGEXP
, expression=>'1=1'
, enable=>TRUE
, regexp_pattern=>'(YYY)(.*)'
, regexp_replace_string=>'XXX\2');
```

Result:

`select c_name from table1;`

c_name

---

XXX NNN

null

where lost the second row value?

Please, help me to understand.

**EDIT**
I found typo in my code, now works correct at matching rows, but other rows are nulls, but must contain original content.

Comment: If it does not support references to the capturing groups in the replacement pattern then you can replace `YYY` with `XXX` and you do not need to match the `(.*)` part.

Comment: Documentation says that Your explanation incorrect: "Replacement string (up to 4000 characters in length) with up to 500 back-references to subexpressions in the form \n, where n is a number between 1 and 9." Or I don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce, neither on a 19c nor a 23c, so probably a bug in the version you have:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.22.0.1.0

SQL> create table table1 (c_name varchar2(100));

Table created.

SQL> insert into table1 select 'zzz' from dual union all select 'XXX NNN' from dual;

2 rows created.

begin
  2  dbms_redact.add_policy( object_name=>'TABLE1'
  3  , policy_name=>'test_redact_policy'
  4  , column_name=>'C_NAME'
  5  , function_type=>DBMS_REDACT.REGEXP
  6  , expression=>'1=1'
  7  , enable=>TRUE
, regexp_pattern=>'(YYY)(.*)'
  9  , regexp_replace_string=>'XXX\2');
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select c_name from table1;

C_NAME
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
zzz
XXX NNN
```

Comment: I've reproduced it at the new installation of 19.3 PDB

Comment: I've reproduced it at the new installation of 21.3 PDB also

Comment: If it is a new installation of 19c or 21c, then patch it to the latest version and try again